# Content overlays header

Tags: html, css, header, sections

I want to make some little difference with my website. I wanted that my content block overlays a header, about 100px (example in screenshot)
[image]
There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/au362ndv/) with structure of my web (Im using a `sections` and bootstrap)
This is my CSS

```
.header{
  background:lightblue;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

section.green{background:green}
section.red{background:red}

section{
  width:100%;
}

section .container{
  background:white;
  width:80%;
  height:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move an element up 100px from it's current position, use `transform: translateY(-100px);`

```css
.header{
  background:lightblue;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

section.green{background:green}
section.red{background:red}

section{
  width:100%;
}

section .container{
  background:white;
  width:80%;
  height:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>

<section class="green">
  <div class="container">
    section 1 content
  </div>
</section>

<section  class="red">
  <div class="container">
    section 2 content
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, in IE too :)